# braintree sandbox and paymentMethodNonce

Tags: php, paypal, braintree

I am testing braintree integration with php and braintree sandbox.
I tested with the static nonce and all is fine and working.
But if I test with testing credit cards and I try to get the paymentMethodNonce from the client I get an error 
Unknown paymentMethodNonce.

I have set my merchant ID and everything, server side I generate the ClientToken. Is it possible to pass the paymentMethodNonce in the sandbox or only on production?

I include this file in the beginning:

```
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('mymerchantid');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('mypublickey');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('myprivatekey');

$clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate();
```

This is my page with the form:

```
<form id="checkout" method="post" action="/checkout/index.php" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="hidden" name="payment_method_nonce" id="payment_method_nonce">
  <input type="submit" value="Pay">
</form>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
  var clientToken = "<?php print $clientToken; ?>";

  braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
    container: "payment-form",
    form: "checkout",
    onPaymentMethodReceived: function (nonce) {
      console.log(nonce);
      var form = document.getElementById('checkout');
      var payment_method_nonce = document.getElementById('payment_method_nonce');
      payment_method_nonce.value = nonce;
      payment_method_nonce.form.submit();
    }
  });
</script>
```

This is the checkout page:

```
$nonce = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"];

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
   'amount' => '10.00',
   'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
));

if ($result->success) {
   echo("Success! Transaction ID: " . $result->transaction->id);
} else if ($result->transaction) {
   echo("Error: " . $result->message);
   echo("<br/>");
   echo("Code: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseCode);
} else {
   echo("Validation errors:<br/>");
   foreach (($result->errors->deepAll()) as $error) {
     echo("- " . $error->message . "<br/>");
     echo("- " . $error->code . "<br/>");
   }
}
```

Comment: I see in the console my nonce passed.. I have a nonce value plus object and type credit card.. still I get as result - Unknown paymentMethodNonce.
- 91565

Comment: Have you tried dumping the value of `$_POST["payment_method_nonce"]` to make sure your nonce is being picked up by the server appropriately?